# how to get last businessday of last month in oralce

Tags: oracle

I have data like this my table

2020-01-01 H

2020-01-02 B

2020-01-03 B

2020-01-04 B

.

2020-01-29 B

2020-01-30 H

2020-01-31 H

2020-01-02 H

2020-02-02 H

2020-02-03 B

2020-02-04 B

2020-02-05 B

.

now my problem is in the current month i need to check third business day i.e in this case 2020-02-05 i need to get last business day of last month. i.e.2020-01-29

Answer (score 0):

> in the current month I need to check third business day

From Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT date_value
FROM   table_name
WHERE  TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') <= date_value
AND    date_value < ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 1)
AND    day_type = 'B'
ORDER BY date_value ASC
OFFSET 2 ROWS
FETCH NEXT ROW ONLY;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (date_value, day_type) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-01-01', 'H' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-02', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-03', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-04', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-05', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-28', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-29', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-30', 'H' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-31', 'H' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-02', 'H' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-02-02', 'H' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-02-03', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-02-04', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-02-05', 'B' FROM DUAL;
```

If the current month was 2020-01 then the output is:

| DATE_VALUE |
| --- |
| 04-JAN-20 |

---

> I need to get last business day of last month

```sql
SELECT date_value
FROM   table_name
WHERE  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -1) <= date_value
AND    date_value < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')
AND    day_type = 'B'
ORDER BY date_value DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

If the current month is 2020-02 then the output is:

| DATE_VALUE |
| --- |
| 29-JAN-20 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/t0BLvWl7)

Comment: I am looking at if the date is 2020-02-05 then i should get last business day of last month as 2020-01-29

Comment: for the 3rd business day of the current month when i run this i am getting 01-Nov-2022 which i am expecting 03-Nov-2022    SELECT date_value
FROM   table_name
WHERE  TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') <= date_value
AND    date_value < ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 1)
AND    day_type = 'B'
ORDER BY date_value ASC
OFFSET 2 ROWS
FETCH NEXT ROW ONLY;

Comment: @Satya It works for me [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iXn3GA0Z)

Answer (score 0):

By adding 2 columns:

```
row_number() over(partition by trunc(date_value,'MM'), day_type order by date_value) as rn_month_asc, 
row_number() over(partition by trunc(date_value,'MM'), day_type order by date_value desc) as rn_month_desc
```

in a month the 3rd business day will have rn_month_asc=3 and day_type ='B' and the latest business day will have rn_month_desc=1 and day_type ='B', and easy to query other situations if you need to.